# how would I tell if the scroll bar has reached the end of post's content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title pretty much speaks for itself. So how would I go about doing that using jQuery or javascript?
I know to tell if the scroll bar has reached the end of a window, it would be something like this.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
alert('you have reached the bottom');
}
});
```

So how would I tell if it has reached a specific section then give the alert?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Granted not a difficult problem to solve, but check out [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)... a very nice plugin to meet your requirements.

A quick example from their site:

```
$('.entry').waypoint(function() {
   alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
});
```

Elegant and easy to read too, and the plugin is very small, < 4kb.

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing this **without a plugin** would be this.

**Example**

```
// calculate where the bottom of the post is positioned
var postBottom = $(".post").offset().top + $(".post").height();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    // check if the bottom of the post is smaller than the window height
    if (postBottom < $(window).height()){
        alert('you have reached the bottom of the post');
    }
});
```

Comment: this also nice, but I just tried it and it keeps alerting me anytime I scroll. thanks though. :)

Comment: Didn't think of that, guess the plugin is the best way to go ;)